# Prechat form details

Tags: liveagent, pre-chat, pre-chat-api

I want to  create case as soon as support agent accept the chat and it is getting created, but now I want to populate the account name automatically from the prechat form, can it be done???
below are my prechat form details for case creation.
[image]

Please let me know if it is possible in any way.